# multiple sks files, calling proper scene based on GVC in SpriteKit

Tags: iphone, swift, ipad, sprite-kit, universal

I have five iPad scenes, and 5 iPhone  Scenes in my GVC I have this, I can call the Welcome Scene and Hud Scene no problem, yet I can not replicate the same calls for the other scenes. I do not know if it is the curly braces, yet I can not seem to call the other iPad scenes it defaults to the iPhone scene. (trust me I was pretty excited when the HUD, showed up.) Can someone give some advice on the structure of my code. Please....

```
import SpriteKit
class GameViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone) {

      if let scene = WelcomeScene(fileNamed:"WelcomeScene") {

        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = GlobalData.Constant.DEV.DEBUG
        skView.showsNodeCount = GlobalData.Constant.DEV.DEBUG
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)


    }

        } else {

            if let scene = WelcomeScenePad(fileNamed: "WelcomeScenePad") {
                let skView = self.view as! SKView
                skView.showsFPS = GlobalData.Constant.DEV.DEBUG
                skView.showsNodeCount = GlobalData.Constant.DEV.DEBUG
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                skView.presentScene(scene)

                if let scene = HudScenePad(fileNamed: "HudScenePad") {
                    let skView = self.view as! SKView
                    skView.showsNodeCount = GlobalData.Constant.DEV.DEBUG
                    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                    skView.presentScene(scene)
                }



            } else  if let scene = WelcomeScene(fileNamed:"WelcomeScene") {

                let skView = self.view as! SKView
                skView.showsFPS = GlobalData.Constant.DEV.DEBUG
                skView.showsNodeCount = GlobalData.Constant.DEV.DEBUG
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }


        }



    }




    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {

            return .AllButUpsideDown

        } else {

            return .All

    }




}


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

   }
```

This bit of code lets me know that the game scene is going to proper sks file, and prints the value in the editor, to verify, this is in my gameOver Function.

```
  if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad ){

        if let _ = SceneTypePad(rawValue: fullSKSNameToLoad + String("Pad")) {

            fullSKSNameToLoad = "fileNamed" + "Pad"

            goToScenePad(SceneTypePad.DebateScene1Pad)
            print(("Went to DebateScenePad"))
            _ = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(3)

            _ = DebateScene1Pad()


        }
    } else  if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone ){
        goToScene(SceneType.DebateScene1)
        (print("Went to DebateScenePhone"))
        _ = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(3)

        _ = DebateScene1()

    }
```

Three secs is too long to wait btw... :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a new static variable to call the SKs pad scene in my GlobalData/Base Scene file. Noob mistake. Word to the wise when duplicating code for the new files double check the variables, when duplicated swift files. Also, it is good to give the mind a break, individuals can not keep their attention span and be sharp after 14 hours of coding.... Take a walk, sort it out with a fresh mind. Deadlines are crucial in this business, yet sometimes pressure can bring about silly decisions that can be easily solved.

```
 static var previousScenePad:SceneTypePad?

 static var nextScenePad:SceneTypePad?
if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone) {

if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad ){

  if let _ = SceneTypePad(rawValue: fullSKSNameToLoad + String("Pad")) {

        fullSKSNameToLoad = "fileNamed" + "Pad"

    }
} else  if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone ){


    }
```

Does work in GVC when calling particular SKS files. Obviously it renders the proper view based upon using the correct fileName "" that is defined in the base class, yes I am aware, that there are better way to use one SKS files, and using camera nodes to adjust views. When it comes to content, and having more space it gives opportunity to create a different experience with more pixels, and more space. Assets are equally important, as in the beginning I was calling the wrong assets per device, I decided to hard code, the scale factors for my look without losing resolution. The end result will be a universal app that works cross platforms. If you optimize right, I was able to condense a 140mb app, to 76mb, even though I added 5 new scenes to my app bundle. Check your background music, check your sound effects, and PNG files. Limit emitters to the effect that looks good. You can always go back and find cleaner approach in the next update!!!